# How to show google drive images in VF Pdf file

Tags: visualforce, pdf, images, google-drive, remote-site-settings

I need to show google drive bulk images in VF PDF file. currently am getting broken image. that image url saved in salesforce and remote site settings.

how can i get that real image in vf pdf file.

Comment: Have you tried static resource ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer but if one image means i will upload in static resource. i am uploading number of images in google drive and getting the google drive image url and saving in salesforce database. i am calling that url in visualforce pdf page. its showng broken image.

Comment: i suggest you to use visualforce component in your visualforce page PDF. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_comp_cust_using.htm

Comment: As mentioned before, downloading the images and storing them as static resource is best possible option you have.

Answer (score 1):

See [Visualforce PDF Rendering Considerations and Limitations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_output_pdf_considerations.htm) where it says:

- **PDF rendering doesn’t support images encoded in the data: URI scheme format.**

You'll need to download the images and store them as static resources.